# Grocery Store Aisle

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, pronunciation-vs-spelling

When speaking the phrase *grocery store aisle,* I leave the **s** in *aisle* silent.  Are there any regional variations of English in which the **s** is not silent?

Comment: Interesting comment here:http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=aisle

Comment: I can add that I've never heard the "s" pronounced in my region (the US - specifically the Northeast - major metropolitan areas + New England).

Comment: No, I certainly know of nowhere in Britain where the s would be pronounced, in *aisle*, *isle* or *island*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OED lists a large number of forms — probably unsurprisingly since it's a Middle English word:

> **Pronunciation:**  Brit. /ʌɪl/ , U.S. /aɪl/
>   **Forms:**
>   **α.** ME **eile,** ME **eill,** ME **ele,** ME **elle,** ME **hele,** ME **ill,** ME **ille,** ME–15 **eyle,** ME–15 **yele,** ME–15 **yle,** ME–18 **ile,** 15 **heyell,** 15 **yell,** 15 **ylle,** 18– **hile** *(Eng. regional (south-west.* and *Isle of Wight));* *Sc.* pre-17 **eyll,** pre-17 **iile,** pre-17 **iill,** pre-17 **ile,** pre-17 **iyle,** pre-17 **iyll,** pre-17 **yell,** pre-17 **yill,** pre-17 **yle,** pre-17 **yll**; N. E. D. (1884) also records a form lME **eille,** lME **ylle.**
>   **β.** lME **ilde,** lME **jlde**, 15 **ȝelde**, 15 **yeld**, 15 **yld.**
>   **γ.** 15 **oyle,** 15 (*Sc.*) 16– **aisle,** 15–17 **ayle,** 16 **oylle,** 17–18 **aile.**
>   **δ.** 15– **isle** (now *nonstandard*).

The only form which has an *s* originated in the 17th century, and that's the form which has survived (apart from the "nonstandard" *isle*).

Regarding the *-s-*, OED has

> The γ. forms show alteration after Middle French, French **aile** wing, etc. The modern standard spelling **aisle,** which was hesitatingly admitted by Johnson (1755), probably shows an alteration of **ayle** after the δ. forms, rather than being in any way directly influenced by the rare Middle French, French **†aisle**.

Thus there is only one form of the word in its history which includes an *-s-* and that may have been influenced by the French ***aile***. OED comments "In Middle French and early modern French spellings with medial -s- this is a purely graphic device serving to indicate the open quality of the vowel."

The word itself derives from Anglo-Norman **ele, eele, eile** "wing of a church" (late 12th cent. or earlier), according to OED, which is directly related to the French *aile*.

Accordingly, it seems reasonable to say that the *-s-* in *aisle* has never been pronounced.

Comment: It appeared to me from glancing at the OED that the s comes rather later than the 15th century suggested by Etymonline (see @mplungian comment). the first example with both an a and an s is 1789.